# Multiple Character sets in Single Table : MySql/Mariadb

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mariadb

I got stuck in a situation need a help/suggestion to make the decision.
I have a table which have almost 20 million rows and rising enormously on duration of every six month. My default character set of the table is utf8mb4.
It consists of primarily 7 columns. Out of which one column needs to be utf8mb4.

I have decided to go for the latin1_swedish_ci for rest of the columns.
Would it hamper the the table? if in the worst scenario, i need to alter the table.

I am stuck whether multiple character sets is good or bad in the case considering the case of number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's be clear on two terms:

- "Character set" is the encoding, such as latin1, utf8, utf8mb4.
- "Collation" is how to sort, as in latin1_swedish_ci, utf8_general_ci, utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci.

There is no problem having different columns using different character sets and/or collation.  And the columns do not need to match the table's *defaults*.

Generally, it is best to use the utf8mb4 character set for all columns.  But this is not a strong requirement.  Mixing does not "hamper" operations.

`ALTER TABLE .. CONVER TO ..` is a way to correctly convert *all* the columns (of one table) to a diff charset, assuming they were correctly encoded according to the old declaration.

`ALTER TABLE .. MODIFY COLUMN x VARCHAR(..) CHARACTER SET ..` is the way to change one column.  Note: the size, default, null/not-null, etc. must be repeated.

Regardless of how you do it, it will take some time to change the charset for one or more columns in a 20M-row table.

When `JOINing` two tables on a string column, it is more efficient if both tables have the same charset and collation for the column you are joining on.